# Watch Kit app with Watch OS 1 and 2

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7, watchkit, watchos

I have some question regarding Apple Watch apps, As per Xcode 7, there is two target for Apple Watch, one which is supporting OS 1 and second which is supporting OS 2. So is it means, If i choose OS2, my app will not run in watch which is having OS 1? Or Similar, If I choose OS 1, my app will not run in watch which is having OS 2?

Can you please explain that?

Answer (score 3):

WatchOS 1 and 2 are fundamentally different. The first one only take data from phone, when second one embed executable code directly on the watch.

I think old app for WatchOS 1 works on WatchOS2, but the reverse isn't true for sure.

Answer (score 2):

YES If you run on watch os1 this will not support watch os2 and vice versa both are different in features ...as watch os 1 do not have memory to save data for iphone app on other hand watch os2 have memory to save iphone app data...

Answer (score 0):

From general reading, theres been no negative reviews of WatchOS 2 compared to 1, the only thing mentioned is further improvement. What I'm getting at is the number of users still using WatchOS 1 now if likely to be absolutely minimal as there is no reason not to upgrade, it really is a no-brainer.